# Tomcat: no xmx/xms value set, where is the heap value being defined?

Tags: linux, java, tomcat, jdk

I have a Tomcat 7 install running with Java 1.7 on a Linux 2.6 server, and `jinfo` shows no `xmx` or `xms` values.  `ps` output shows nothing set for xmx/xms on the command line for the java process.  Tomcat is running fine, but I am curious what settings will be used for heap when xmx and xms are not being set anywhere.  They aren't in catalina.sh and setenv.sh doesn't exist.  What does the JVM use in this scenario?

Comment: a simple google search let to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897476/tomcat-7-how-to-set-initial-heap-size-correctly, unless I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: You are misunderstanding.  I known how to set the values, I am asking what values are used when these settings are not set any where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
```

And looking for value you want. In my machine, output is:

```
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1570766848      {product}           
uintx MaxNewSize                                = 18446744073709486080{product}           
uintx MaxPermHeapExpansion                      = 5439488         {product}           
uintx MaxPermSize                               = 174063616       {pd product}
```

**Note**

- [java man page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)
- [Garbage Collector Ergonomics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

Comment: Very helpful!  Is that measured in bits?  Where does this default setting come from?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal: According to the man page, the default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration, see more details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html